# Lazy Haskell pattern in a boolean case expression?

Tags: haskell, lazy-evaluation

In a `case` expression such as:

```
case b of True  -> 17
          False -> 18
```

would there be *any* laziness in:

```
case b of True  -> 17
          _     -> 18
```

i.e. using the `_` pattern instead of `False`?

If there is no laziness for `Bool`, is that also the case for:

```
data Three = One|Two|Three
case x of One -> 17
          _   -> 18
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. `b` is evaluated to WHNF to check which `Bool` constructor was used. At that point, there is nothing left to evaluate.

Comment: Is that also the case with something like `data Three = One|Two|Three` in a `case` expression such as `case x of {One -> 17; _ -> 18 }` ?

Comment: @user643722 Yes, there's nothing left to be lazy about. Think about constructors as layers of a value. Your case expression inspects the top layer, so this layer of any value `x` must be evaluated. With types like `Bool` or `Three` there is nothing below the first layer.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I get it that the layer is now, let's say, exposed. But the `case` expression (for `Three`) has only determined whether it equals `One`. It's not yet know whether it's `Two` or `Three`, no?

Comment: @user643722 - Thats right - therefore the _ pattern may save a comparision. But note that the compiler is clever enough to know that if something is Bool, but not True, then it must be False, so in your original question, you save nothing by writing _ (If I do not err, this will be rewritten to *if b then 17 else 18* anyway)

Comment: @user643722 As @Ingo said, you can save a comparison, but this isn't what is usually referred to as lazyness. Matching only the `One` constructor, then having a wild card for the alternative is no different than a `switch` statement in imperative languages that uses a `default` branch rather than an explicit `case` for all possibilities.

Answer (score 2):

No, this case expression will evaluate b, but of course only **if** an expression wherein it is contained is itself evaluated for whatever reason.

For example, in

```
(42, case b of { True -> 43; False -> 41})
```

b will not be evaluated until the second element of the tuple is.

In general, a irrefutable pattern will not increase laziness if previous patterns make it necessary to evaluate the value - remember that case patterns are tried strictly sequential in the order they are given. And since there is nothing like "unevaluting" an always evaluated value, the case expression remains evaluated.